# move through treeview backwards

Tags: c#, treeview

[image]

I wish to move backwards - lets say im in "Backgrounds" node. Then i wish to move:

```
->backgrounds
->component 6
->components
->assembly 3
->component 5
->component 4
->components
->assembly 2
->component 3
 ...
```

can anyone help me.

Comment: Do you want to navigate to the last node in the tree (wrap around), or do you want to move the node to the end?

Comment: well i want to check some values of each node "backwords" like filtering.

Comment: Ah, so you want to, based on the picture, go from "Backgrounds" to "Component 6"?

Comment: yes. check each node starting from "the bottom" of each treeview.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken what you want is called a rightmost traversal in postorder. You can read about tree Traversal here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since my comment was helpful I'm posting this answer.

What you want is called a Rightmost traversel in postorder. You can do it recursively like this:

```
public void traverse(TreeNode t)
{
    for (int i = t.Nodes.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        traverse(t.Nodes[i]);
    }
    /*Do something*/
}
```

You can read more about tree traversal methods here: [Tree traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal)

Comment: I have one more additional question. I want to check each node of my treeview wethear they meet some condition. What should I do if i want to start it from one of node that is inside treeview but check condition for all "above" nodes (Like in first post e.g. starting node is "Backgrounds".

Comment: @santBart The easy solution would be to just do nothing, until you reach the node you want to start from. Otherwise you will have to alter the algorithm somehow to start from the node you want, then figure out the next node to visit and repeat that until you're done. I am not entirely sure how you can do it efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

This is a built-in capability, you can use the TreeNode.PrevVisibleNode property.  Like this:

```
    private void MoveUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var node = treeView1.SelectedNode;
        if (node != null && node.PrevVisibleNode != null) 
            treeView1.SelectedNode = node.PrevVisibleNode;
        treeView1.Focus();
    }
```

Comment: it works only if all nodes are expanded. I cant be sure that user would do it.